# IIS7 local network issue?

Tags: asp.net, iis-7

I have successfully hosted a website on my pc which i can open by the following path:

```
"localhost/basel/index.aspx"
```

Now i wanted all pc's on the network to access the website by using the following path:

```
"http://myip/basel/index.aspx"
//It keeps giving me 404, and even when i enter it on my pc it gives the same error.
```

All pc's are on the network are connected with no problems and can share files. What am i doing wrong ?

Comment: What happens if you browse http://myip only?

Comment: with "myip" i meant my ipaddress, and i get an error if do that.

Comment: I know you meant to say your ip :) You should see the "welcome" message of IIS7. If you get an error, the best guess is that you're not using the correct ip.

Comment: I am sure that it's the right one, and about the welcome message it will not appear since there is no website that reference the intpup. I only have one website that i have created and added it to the iis

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can ensure that the site is bound to the correct I.P address by removing the All unassigned in IIS  and explicitly setting the I.P binding. The I.P address you select should be from one of the following ranges for a private network.

10.0.0.0 – 10.255.255.255 | 172.16.0.0 – 172.31.255.255 | 192.168.0.0 – 192.168.255.255

[image]

Comment: i have tried both, unassigned and assigned. None works for me

Comment: What is the exact URL you are typing on the remote machines? Did it match the I.P in the drop down?